# "Unbelief" or "disbelief"

Tags: difference, vocabulary

If someone believes in God but rejects His words or orders or speaks some blasphemous words, is it called "unbelief" or "disbelief"?

Comment: Theology questions are asked on [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions), there are also [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions), [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions), [Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions) and [Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions) sites, possibly others too.

Comment: Generally speaking, ***disbelief*** has the broader "reach" for all senses of *unpreparedness, unwillingness, or inability to believe that something is the case*, whereas the [now significantly less common ***unbelief***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unbelief%2Cdisbelief&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunbelief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisbelief%3B%2Cc0) usually more specifically refers to *absence (or **rejection**) of belief, **especially religious belief***.

Answer (score 2):

Neither. It is blasphemy or apostasy or heresy.

Disbelief is a general "not accepting that something is true" it is often nothing to do with god (though it might be).

> His disbelief when I told him I was pregnant was obvious.
>   His disbelief in god was long held.

Unbelief tends to be an absence of belief (in a particular religion), but is rather rare.  "Unbeliever" is sometimes used pejoratively by religious people.

If someone believes in the existence of god, but rejects him that neither disbelief nor unbelief.